# Plupload transmission with submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to send all files with the submit-button. The upload is working fine, but the transmission with the submit button is not working properly. When I will send the form, the files are uploaded but the transmission is not going to dump.php. I need to select the button again to get the transmission to dump.php.
I’m using this code with simple numeric array as example:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="dump.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$num = array('1','2','3');
foreach ($num as $upid) {
?>
<div id="uploader<?php echo $upid;?>">
    <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Setup html5 version
    var uploader<?php echo $upid;?>  = $("#uploader<?php echo $upid;?>").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        url : 'upload.php?frageid=2',
        rename : true,
        filters : {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '10mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
            ]
        },
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        }
    });

    // Handle the case when form was submitted before uploading has finished
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        // Files in queue upload them first
        if (uploader<?php echo $upid;?>.plupload('getFiles').length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader<?php echo $upid;?>.on('complete', function() {
                $('#form')[<?php echo $upid;?>].submit();
            });
            uploader<?php echo $upid;?>.plupload('start');
            return false; // Keep the form from submitting
        }
    });  
});
</script>
<?php
 }
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Plupload but from the documentation it doesn't seem to be intended to work inside a form, instead it performs the upload logic by itself.

The url which is receiving the data is specified when you create the uploader object. In your example it is

```
url : 'upload.php?frageid=2',
```

If you want to trigger the upload of files by a button you should simply create a standalone button (whitout a form), like this:

```
<button type="button" id="sendButton">[Button text]</button>
```

Then listen on its click event

```
$('#sendButton').click(function(){
    uploader.plupload('start');
});
```

This snippet uses jQuery because you are already using it in your example.

**Edit:**

As I mentioned before, in the data used to create the uploader object you specify the url so you will have to change that to the route you have to handle the data.

```
url : 'dump.php',
```

In the server side you use the superglobal `$_FILES` to access the uploaded files, this is a simplified example for handling one file.

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES["file"]["error"]) {
  die('{"OK": 0}');
}

$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/$fileName");

die('{"OK": 1}');
?>
```

This snippet was taken from Plupload's documentation, its available [here](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started), you should really check it out. Also, it clearly states that this code does not perform any checks so **you should really not use this as is**, but rather *take it into account* when you make your own.

Comment: Thanks for help Kevin. I'm not much experienced at JavaScript. Your solution is working fine, but only for upload files. I removed my form and created the button. How can I realise the transmission to dump.php like in my form? I have to send more data. On the next page (dump.php), I’ll check the $_POST REQUEST and put data in my database. Actually, when I press the submit button, I can see that the files are uploaded but not checking the REQUEST to put some messages when something is going wrong.